# Is there a way I can solve this syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Am getting SyntaxError: 'return' outside function on my code.
I have checked the indentation and it's fine, can someone help me?
Here's my code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import form
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    email = form.cleaned_data['name']
    message = form.cleaned_data['name']
    sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
    cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']
    
    recipients = ['hillariouskelly@gmail.com']
    if cc_myself:
        recipients.append(sender)

    send_mail(name, email, message, sender, recipients)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns from a function, therefore `return` must be inside of a function definition. You have a `return` outside of a function definition somewhere.

The error message will tell you which line the problem appears on.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import form
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def submit(form):
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['name']
        message = form.cleaned_data['name']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']
    
        recipients = ['hillariouskelly@gmail.com']
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(sender)

        send_mail(name, email, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```